# D3 dots do not match curved area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello I am trying to create an area chart with d3 and am trying to match d3's generated coordinates with a d3.symbolCircle.

This is what I have:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bozoQa

You will notice that in the current state the dots do not match the generated lines.

The reason for that is because of line 133.

```
const area = d3.area()
    .x((d, i) => xScale(data.xAxis.categories[i]))
    .y0(viewModel.height)
    .y1((d) => yScale(d))
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
```

This creates the area as curved instead of a straight line. If I remove that the dots would match and it would work but I need this chart to have curved lines.

Taking this into consideration how can I set the dots in the correct position no matter what type of curve I will be setting on the area chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use another interpolation function, for example, `curveCardinal`. Look at [this demo page](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529), when you can choose interpolation function for your case (click on names of functions appears/disappears the corresponding line).

Look at my fork of your pen with `curveCardinal` - https://codepen.io/levvsha/pen/YrBEzN?editors=1010

```
const area = d3.area()
  .x((d, i) => xScale(data.xAxis.categories[i]))
  .y0(viewModel.height)
  .y1((d) => yScale(d))
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
```